# Can I get params to group parameters?

Tags: grails, data-binding, parameters

Given a form like this:

[image: form]

I want to do this in my controller:

```
params.books.each { book -> println "title: ${book.title}, isbn: ${book.isbn}" }
```

and get this output:

```
title: t1, isbn: i1
title: t2, isbn: i2
title: t3, isbn: i3
```

Is there a way to do this by just setting the names of form elements correctly?

I tried `books[0].title, books[0].isbn, books[1].title...` but `params` has the `[i]` in the key...

I did find something which works [here](http://www.intelligrape.com/blog/2011/10/24/grails-binddata-to-collections/) but I was hoping that `params` could figure all this out on its own.

Comment: I don't think it's possible with params as it needs to have a set behaviour. In the past i've done similar however just by using the groupBy closure on params (http://mrhaki.blogspot.com.au/2009/09/groovy-goodness-using-groupby-method.html). Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You can loop around on one label|textfield|textfield and insert the value dynamically for that loop you can use **status** and **counter** gsp loop variables where status being particular book in loop.